# Email campaign website with API that takes email addresses

Tags: webapp-rec

I would like to take advantage of a third party service to send out emails, but I don't want to duplicate my user list.

Is there a service that offers an API that will accept recipient emails rather than force me to pre-submit a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all email apps have APIs

Check out these:

- [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [CampaignMonitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/)
- [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com)
- [iContact](http://icontact.com)

Comment: Thank you, SendGrid is the type of service I am after (sending emails rather than managing lists). Any others offer this type of service?

Answer (score 1):

I can heavily recommend [PostmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com/) if you are sending transactional emails instead of newsletters / mail lists. It has a neat API and great support.

Comment: Thank you! If I need to go over the free 200 mails/day from SendGrid, I'll give these guys a try.

Answer (score 0):

I use MailChimp, they have a great upload, as well as a great API to allow you to push submissions to them as user want to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the software I develop. 
http://www.convincingmail.com

It is an email marketing solution instals on your server and allows you to send email marketing campaigns. 
No need to share your list double verify and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try [Email It - Email Marketing and List Manager](http://www.emailit.co). They have a really good email marketing API.